# NIntegrate over statistical variables with parameter

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

Essentially, what I am trying to do is the following: `Integrate` a function which contains the parameter k

```
Integrate[k*x^2, {x, 0, 100}] == 0.01
(1000000 k)/3 == 0.01
```

and then find k

```
Simplify[solve[(1000000 k)/3 == 0.01, k]]
solve[1. k == 3.*10^-8, k]
```

Unfortunately my function is a bad-ass combination of statistics, with variables l and m extracted from a size 10000 of exponential ordered statistics (two arrays of 10000). This is what I managed to do so far:

```
M = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], {20, 10000}];
M2 = Transpose[Sort /@ Transpose[M]];
MatrixForm[M2];
l = Part[M2, 5];
m = Part[M2, 10];

badass[k_?NumericQ] = NIntegrate[(Beta[((CDF[ExponentialDistribution[1],
 (m + k (m - l))])/(CDF[ExponentialDistribution[1], l])), 1,4])*
(20!/(20 - 2)!)*(Exp[-l])*((Exp[-m])^(20 - 2))*(Exp[-m])*((Exp[-m])^(20 - 2)), 
{l, 0, Infinity}, {m, l,Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 20,
 Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}] == 0.01


("The integrand 95\ E^(-l-37\m)\ \
(1-(1-Piecewise[{<<1>>},0]/Piecewise[<<2>>])^4) has evaluated to \
non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with \
boundaries {{0,1},{0,1}}.")

("The integrand 95\ E^(-l-37\m)\ \
(1-(1-Piecewise[{<<1>>},0]/Piecewise[<<2>>])^4) has evaluated to \
Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the \
region with boundaries {{4.48443*10^-67,2.48466*10^-32},{0,0.5}}"
```

If the `NIntegral` doesn't go, neither the findroot. I already know that for        k=3.955 the integral has to go to 0.01 (I am reconstructing the findings of a paper). Assigning k=3.955, same overflow error. The function seems to have a singularity around 0 (plot not included). Any help would be appreciated because I've been smashing my heard around this for a couple of weeks and I am relatively new to *Mathematica*.